# How to separate integers and doubles in a vector?

Tags: r, data.table

I read in a column of a data frame using `fread` from the `data.table` package. Approximately half of the numbers in the vector have double precision while the other half only have integer precision.

```
head(data$value)
#[1] 3 1.2 3.1 1 1.0 5
```

I want to separate the vector into two by precision however when I use the `typeof` function all values are returned as doubles so I can't use that to differentiate the two.

The output would result in two separate vectors such as:

```
single <- c(3,1,5)
double <- c(1.2,3.1,1.0)
```

Comment: Can you please show the expected output?

Comment: It is an integer but it has double precision so i would like to separate it into the double group

Comment: If the variable is a double, then how come some values are `1` and some `1.0`...Am I missing something? Please share a reproducible example (`dput(head(data$value))`)

Comment: "It is an integer but it has double precision" this sentence makes no sense. Please clarify how 1.0 is different from 1, and why when you print `data$value` some numbers appear formatted as integers and others as doubles, since R usually prints all the numbers with the same format...

Comment: Maybe the values in this column result from two different kinds of measures: some of them rough (--> integer precision) and some others made with a device that allows a better accuracy (--> double precision). And the OP needs to tell them apart. So a reasonable solution might be to read them as character using `fread` with the `colClasses` argument, and then use @ytu's method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To distinguish 1.0 from 1, I got an idea (maybe not so talented though):  using regular expressions to separate them.

```
single <- data$value[!grepl("\\.", data$value)]
double <- data$value[grepl("\\.", data$value)]
```

In this case, `data$value` is first coerced into characters in `grepl`, and then the literal dot is searched element-wise, generating logical values to subset `data$value`.

Comment: You can even directly read the values as character with `fread("file.csv", colClasses = c(value = "character"))`.

Comment: SAme here. Run your methodology to split this vector `x <- c(3, 1.2, 3.1, 1, 1.0, 5)`

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that your vector is x, you can split on the values that when rounded are the same with the originaals, i.e.

```
x <- c(3, 1.2, 3.1, 1, 1.0, 5)

split(x, round(x) == x)

$`FALSE`
[1] 1.2 3.1

$`TRUE`
[1] 3 1 1 5
```

Comment: I don't think 1.0 should be regarded as 1 here. They are different in this case.

Comment: I appreciate this but 1.0 has double precision as compared to 1. For this reason I'd like to designate them differently

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
single<-data[grepl("[.]",data$value),"value"]
double<-data[!grepl("[.]",data$value),"value"]

single
[1] 1.2 3.1 1.0
Levels: 1 1.0 1.2 3 3.1 5
> double
[1] 3 1 5
Levels: 1 1.0 1.2 3 3.1 5
```

Comment: But how did you print different formats?? Now try to apply your methodology to split this vector `x <- c(3, 1.2, 3.1, 1, 1.0, 5)`

Comment: I'm with you, but in the question head(data$value)
#[1] 3 1.2 3.1 1 1.0 5 appears like character format with the same value presented with and without "." (E.g 1 and 1.0)

Comment: As per OP *when I use the typeof function all values are returned as doubles*

Comment: I think the question is not so clear.

Comment: Well that's for sure...

Comment: My code works only if you are in this condition: data<-data.frame(value=c("3", "1.2", "3.1", "1", "1.0", "5"))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166703/discussion-between-terru-theterror-and-sotos).